# Can't understand the rule about explicit specialization declaration for menber of an unspecialized class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The rule of explicit specialization declaration for member of an unspecialized class template in the latest c++ standard is as the following:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that the declaration **shall not explicitly specialize a class member template** if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well. In such an explicit specialization declaration, the keyword template followed by a template-parameter-list shall be provided instead of the template<> preceding the explicit specialization declaration of the member. The types of the template-parameters in the template-parameter-list shall be the same as those specified in the primary template definition.

Honestly, I have many confusions about this paragraph. Please consider the example written in the following of this rule.

```cpp
template <class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
  };
};
template <class Y> 
template <>
void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { }   // error: B<double> is specialized but  
                                  // its enclosing class template A is not
```

As the comment says, this explicit specialization declaration for member `mf2` is ill-formed, however, I can't understand why this delcaration is ill-formed through this rule.  My reason is the bolded wording, it says that the declaration **shall not explicitly specialize a class member template** if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.  However, in this example, the declaration is a explicit specialization for `mf2` which is not a class member template instead it is a member of a class template. So strictly speaking, it does not conform the condition of the exception, why the declaration is ill-formed? I feel this paragraph is unclear. So digging in the further, I found the defective report that is [CWG529](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#529).

It says that:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, that is, the corresponding template prefix may specify a template-parameter-list instead of template<> and the template-id naming the template be written using those template-parameters as template-arguments. In such a declaration, the number, kinds, and types of the template-parameters shall be the same as those specified in the primary template definition, and the template-parameters shall be named in the template-id in the same order that they appear in the template-parameter-list. **An unspecialized template-id shall not precede the name of a template specialization in the qualified-id naming the member**.

After thinking for a bit more, I still think the proposal is not sufficient to interpret these cases, for example:

```cpp
template <class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
  };
};

template<>
template <class T> 
void A<int>::B<T>::mf2(){}
```

First, `mf2` is not a template specialization, however the template-id `B<T>` precedes `mf2`, this declaration is ill-formed. It still can't interpret this example too:

```cpp
template <class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
  };
};

template<>
template <class T> 
template <class U> 
void A<int>::B<T>::mf1(U){}
```

`mf1` is a template name but not a template-id (i.e, template specialization)

So after thinking these ill-formed examples, IMHO, Is this modified sentence  the intent of this rule?

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized. In such an explicit specialization declaration, the keyword template followed by a template-parameter-list shall be provided instead of the template<> preceding the explicit specialization declaration of the member. The types of the template-parameters in the template-parameter-list shall be the same as those specified in the primary template definition. **In this declaration, each `template-id` in nested-name-specifier that is unspecialized shall be explicit specialized**.

```cpp
template <class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> 
    void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
  };
};

template<>   // explicit specialization for `B`
template<class T>
class A<int>::B{
   template<class U>
   void mf1(U);
};

template<>
template<class T>
template <class U> 
void A<int>::B<T>::mf1(U){}
```

This example will be ill-formed, although `B<T>` is unspecialized but it has been explicit specialized. Is this a good interpretation? Or, If I misread the original rule, please interpret how to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The rule [[temp.expl.spec]/p16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#expl.spec-16) applies recursively, it says simply that nothing can be specialized unless the entire chain leading up to it is also specialized.

We don't even get to `mf2` because it's not possible to specialize `B` for every possible `A`:

```
template <class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
  };
};

template <class Y> 
template <>
void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { }  // Not OK - can't specialize B for every possible A

template <> 
template <>
void A<int>::B<double>::mf2() { }  // OK - full specialization
```

> ```
> template <class T1> class A {
>   template<class T2> class B {
>     template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
>     void mf2();
>   };
> };
>
> template <>
> template <class T> 
> void A<int>::B<T>::mf2(){}
> ```

Same story: can't specialize `mf2` for every possible `A<int>::B`.

The last example with a specialized `A<int>::B` is somewhat confusing, but the same rule still applies:

```
template <class T1> class A {
template <class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> 
    void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
};
};

template <>
template <class T>
class A<int>::B {   // explicit specialization for `B`
    template<class U>
    void mf1(U);
};

template <>
template <class T>
template <class U> 
void A<int>::B<T>::mf1(U){} // OK (not a specialization, but an out-of-line definition)

template <>
template <class T>
template <> 
void A<int>::B<T>::mf1(double){} // Not OK again, the entire chain must be specialized

template <>
template <>
template <> 
void A<int>::B<double>::mf1(double){} // OK - full specialization
```

CWG [529](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#529) attempts to address the fact that the wording in [[temp.expl.spec]/p16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#expl.spec-16) is confusing in that it talks about a *"specialization"* of a nested class when no such specialization was actually declared. IMHO, CWG 529 fails to acknowledge that there *is* a specialization at every nesting level, only it is hypothetical. Given the first example:

```
template <class T1> class A {
  template<class T2> class B {
    template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
    void mf2();
  };
};

template <class Y> 
template <>
void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { }
```

There is no `template <class Y> template <> class A<Y>::B {};`. But if there was one, it would not have compiled (again, can't specialize `B` for every possible `A`).

Comment: In order to clear this problem, Does the wording "explicitly specialize" mean that exists an explicit specialization for the entity and the wording "unspecialized" mean that a template-id whose template-arguments-list contain some template-parameters?  If they are, then consider this example `template <>
template <class T>
template <> 
void A<int>::B<T>::mf1(double){}` , where `mf1` is a class member template, the declaration is used to explicitly specialize `mf1`, its enclosing `B<T>` has been explicitly specialized , as said in the comment you write(// explicit specialization for `B`).

Comment: why does this declaration violate [temp#expl.spec-16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#expl.spec-16)?

Comment: And back to this example, `template <class Y> template <> void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { }`, Isn't this declaration used to explicitly specialize `mf2`? where `mf2` is not a **template**, why this sentence "except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well." can be applied to it? Although the enclosing class of `mf2` , namely `A<Y>` is not explicitly specialized, however `mf2` is not a **template**.

Comment: In other words, if the sentence can be applied, the declaration must explicitly specialized a template. Right?

Comment: 1) See "*the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well**". `mf1(double)` is an explicit specialization and `B<T>` is its enclosing template, which is not an explicit specialization. Hence the violation.

Comment: 2) See "*the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well*". `B<double>` is an explicit specialization (albeit only "visual" - this is the subject of CWG 529) and `A<Y>` is its enclosing template, which is not an explicit specialization. Hence the violation.

Comment: For you 2) answers, Does it mean that `B<double>` is explicitly specialized by the declaration "template <class Y> template <> void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { }", although that declaration is used to declare `mf2` rather than `B<double>`? I.E, `explicitly specialized` does not mean there shall be a **explicit specialization** for that entity? instead, `explicitly specialized` means that a template-id whose template-arguments-list does not contain any template-parameter?

Comment: For your 1) answers, Isn't this declaration an explicit specialization? namely, `template <> template <class T> class A<int>::B {   // explicit specialization for B template<class U> void mf1(U); };` , that is `B<T>` has been explicitly specialized due to the explicit specialization aforementioned, and `B<T>` is the enclosing class of mf1(double). Does me have any misunderstanding about "explicitly specialized"?

Comment: I think it's definitely the wording "explicitly specialized" that makes me confused, how to read this wording? Does it refer to **an explicit specialization declaration** which declares the entity or only refer to a template-id whose template-arguments are all non template-parameter?